# Rails creating model by collection_ids how to prevent re-association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Lets say i have two models

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wheels
end

class Wheel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Car will be created with Car with wheel_ids = [1,2,3])

How would i check if some of wheel is not associated to another car already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And how about this? But somehow i am not confident about this..

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

validate  :check_reassociation_wheels, on: [:create,:update]

  def check_reassociation_wheels
    wheel_ids.each do |id|
      wheel = Wheel.find(id)
      errors.add(:base, "Cannot reasociate wheel") unless (wheel.car_id.nil? || wheel.car_id == self.id)
    end  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

checking a single wheel

```
wheel = Wheel.last
wheel.car.present? # => if false then it has no association to car
```

checking all wheel with no association

```
wheels = Wheel.join(:car).where(:car => { :id => nil}) # => not tested yet but should work
```